# Remove all duplicates except last instance

Tags: r, duplicates

So I have a dataset in R with the following layout as an example:

```
ID Date Tally
1 2/1/2011 1
2 2/1/2011 2
3 2/1/2011 3
1 2/1/2011 4
2 2/1/2011 5
1 2/1/2011 6
3 2/1/2011 7
4 2/1/2011 8
2 2/1/2011 9
```

I want to remove all instances except the LAST instance of the post id. Right now everything I can find online, and functions I am using is removing everything except the FIRST instance.

So my new data frame would look like:

```
ID Date Tally
1 2/1/2011 6
3 2/1/2011 7
4 2/1/2011 8
2 2/1/2011 9
```

How do I do this? Right now I am only able to keep the first instance. I want it to do the opposite? Any help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `!rev(duplicated(rev(ID)))` to filter out all but the last unique occurrences.

To get the dataset filtered, use `dataset[!rev(duplicated(rev(dataset$ID))),]`

Comment: What to do if you want to retain the first five and remove the rest of duplicates?

Comment: @VipinVerma Modify a logical vector made with `duplicated`to change the first 5 FALSEs to TRUEs. Then use that to index the original.

Answer (score 29):

Wouldn't this just be the standard case for using the 'fromLast' parameter to `duplicated`?

```
 dat[ !duplicated(dat[, c("ID", "Date")], fromLast=T),]
#---------
  ID     Date Tally
6  1 2/1/2011     6
7  3 2/1/2011     7
8  4 2/1/2011     8
9  2 2/1/2011     9
```

Your example was not rich enough to tell whether you needed the "Date" column in the test fro duplication, so perhaps you could simplify. I'm leaving it in to illustrate that `duplicated` has a data.frame method. I prefer `!duplicated` to `unique` because it allows easy access to the set complement if you are comparing groups.

Comment: (+1) Indeed. :-) However, I have a problem with `duplicated.data.frame`, because the code is basically `duplicated(do.call("paste", c(x, sep = "\r")), fromLast = fromLast)`, which, as the help page points out, "may be imperfect if the data frame has characters with embedded carriage returns or columns which do not reliably map to characters".

Answer (score 4):

Using a `data.table` join, you can set `mult = 'last'`

For example

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF, key = 'id')

# join with the unique ID values
DT[unique(DT[,list(ID)]), mult= 'last']

   ID     Date Tally
1:  1 2/1/2011     6
2:  2 2/1/2011     9
3:  3 2/1/2011     7
4:  4 2/1/2011     8
```

If you knew the unique IDs you could also any of the following

```
DT[.(1:4), mult='last']
DT[list(1:4), mult = 'last']
```

Answer (score 4):

Use dplyr:

```
data <- data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(which.max(Tally))
```