# Remove certain duplicate row - keep only the entry with the latest creation date

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a dataframe `df` like this:

```
ID     CreationDate(d.m.Y)    ...
x      12.10.2015             ...
y      09.05.2015             ...
x      18.10.2015             ...
...    ...                    ...
```

I am aware of the `duplicated()` and `unique()` functions, so I could find out which IDs are duplicated by calling `df$ID[duplicated(df$ID)]`. I could then easily remove those datasets from the table - but what I want to do is **keep** only one of them from the data table: the one that was created last (has a "bigger" CreationDate).

In the example given I would like to have the first row removed because its CreationDate is earlier than the third row's. In this case it is also the first occurence, but that is not certain in the real data.

I am lost and do not have an idea how to solve this. I would be really grateful for help or any advice! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `unique(setDT(df)[order(-as.Date(CreationDate, '%d.%m.%Y'))], by ='ID')`

Comment: So, if there are 5 duplicates, you only want to remove the last one, keeping the other 4?

Comment: If there were 5 duplicates I would only want to keep the entry with the latest CreationDate.

Comment: Because keeping the first record only is exactly what `df[!duplicated(df$ID), ]` does, so if you can first sort by creation date then you probably just want the default `duplicated` behavior.

Comment: Great - I didn't have that idea. I was already looking into applying strange formations of ```sapply```... Thank you!! Feel free to post your comments as answers.

Comment: I don't see how my question was asked before in that other thread..

Comment: I think it is a duplicate although not the one that was cited: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641924/remove-all-duplicates-except-last-instance/15643072#15643072 (which seems sufficiently congruent if you just omit the `!`)

Comment: Yes, 42's suggestion is a better match. I don't know of a way to switch the one marked as duplicate other than re-open then re-close.